How can adjust ylabel font location in matplotlib if they are attached?

Here is my plot.
I tried rotation but it is still attach.
How can I detach of them and properly show them?
However, I also have 2 more y-axis tick labels.
If adjust then, I want to make same format for total 4 y-axis tick labels.
Here is code.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_ylim([0, 0.7])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.set_xticks([5, 15, 25, 35])
ax2.set_yticks([0.1156, 0.1904, 0.2062, 0.4879])

ax2.plot([5, 15, 25, 35], [0.1156, 0.1904, 0.2062, 0.4879], linewidth=2, color='black')
ax2.plot(40, 0.7)


ax2.set_yticklabels(['24', '40', '43', '103'], minor=False, fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')


I added code. Please refer to it.

Try to avoid hardcoding fontsize=... and use fig.tight_layout() at the end. Otherwise, define the figsize=(width, height) parameter in plt.subplots with big enough height so that labels with a given font size do not overlap.

Cool. That's the what I wanted answer. Increasing figsize made clear of my problem. Thanks.

If you need to prevent overlaping, you can either increase figure size (set_size_inches) or\and reduce fontsize inside set_yticks:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 8)
ax1.plot([5, 15, 25, 35], [0.1156, 0.1904, 0.2062, 0.4879], linewidth=2, color='black')
ax1.set_ylim([0, 0.7])
ax1.set_xlim([0, 40])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim([0, 0.7])
secondary_y_ticks = [0.1156, 0.1904, 0.2062, 0.4879]
secondary_y_label = [24, 40, 43, 103]
ax2.set_yticks(secondary_y_ticks , secondary_y_label, fontsize=9)

Output:


Seems like you missed ax2.set_ylim([0, 0.7])

Thank you for you comment. It is in the ax1.  ax1.set_ylim([0, 0.7])

Your right ticks are biased downward because the topmost point for them is 1, while the top point of the left axis is set to 0.7

@Vitalizzare, yes, you are right, fixed now.

@Gооd_Mаn Thanks for your answer.
